# How to change the visibility of a label through typecript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a text label which is initially hidden. On clicking a button I want to make it visible but I failed to do so. I would be glad if anyone could help me with it

HTML Code

```
<label for="Validi"  class="validi" id="alert" >Invalid Credentials. Please try again</label>
```

SCSS Code

```
.validi {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I want to change the visibility to "visible" through my typescript file on clicking a button.

Comment: instead of `visibility` use condition for `show hide` label

Comment: You can use `[ngClass]` on your `<label>` element. https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: You can also use *ngIf as you have included angular tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

> .html

```
<label for="Validi" class="validi" id="alert" *ngIf="error">Invalid Credentials. Please try again</label>
<button (click)="showError()">Show Error</label> //OR
<button (click)="error=true">Show Error</label>
```

> .ts

```
error: boolean = false;

showError(){
  this.error = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

example.html

```
<label for="Validi" *ngIf="show" class="validi" id="alert" >Invalid Credentials. Please try again</label>
<button type="button" (click)="show = !show">Click me !</button>
```

example.ts

```
public show = true;
```

example.css

```
.validi {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: @BhargavChudasama your using a function

Comment: see question `On clicking a button I want to make it visible`

Comment: and its not say `toggle label on button click`